# Electron require mystery

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using electron 1.5.

On the render process I have tried three different ways of including react. All work, and that has me realy confused. Can anyone explain?

1. I have put react directly in the window.html

> ```
> <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
> <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
> ```

2. I have removed it from the window.html and put it in the window.js

> require('react'); require('react-dom')

3. I have removed it both from the window.js and window.html, and it STILL WORKS.

I am using Babel with the es2016 preset to process the following JSX file:

(counter.js) is being read in in the window.html

```
<script src="jsx/Counter.js"></script>
```

Counter.jsx

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello Again, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}

class CountWidget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.value}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.onIncrement}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onDecrement}>-</button>
      </div>);
  }
}
```

I am not using any bundlers, or builders, just babel.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "index",
  "main": "main.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.draper.com/ysg4206/NodeWork.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^1.0.0",
    "t7": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016-node5": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": ">=1.4.15",
    "electron-devtools-installer": ">=2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "sourceMaps": "inline",
    "presets": [
      "react",
      "es2016-node5"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess You've to enable debug in electron and see where is it including else

Comment: Are you compiling the jsx or are you including it as `<script src=".../Counter.jsx">`? The `react.js` script is not meant to be used in production. In production you're supposed to compile the jsx (the react.js script is simply a browser-side jsx compiler) and just include the generated js file without including `react.js`.

Comment: @num8er, yes, I have dev-tools going, and yes, I seethe react/dist/react.js and react-dom/dist/readt-dom.js, I just am scratching my head, since both the HTML and .js do not require or source it! Even more curious is that the redux does not show at all, and I do require it, but not <src>. I suspect some caching is going on from the file://

Comment: @slebetman, I am doing the script source on the .js, which babel is generating from the .jsx

Comment: seems like so there is somewhere some packer exist. Check if there is any gulp, grunt, webpack.

Comment: @num8er: It's not a packer. It's just how React.js works. It is not a library but a compiler for a language invented by Facebook called jsx. It compiles down to pure js so it does not depend on any external libraries. For development Facebook also created a browser based compiler called react.js but the OP is pre-compiling on the server so he does not need react.js

Comment: @num8er well, that sounds smart. but I don't use bundlers, don't see the need for desktop apps in electron to bundle (just added the package.json to the top note).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My eyes got crossed from looking at too much Javascript code. I am using Visual Studio Code, and it has a insert comment feature (CTRL-/) or SHFT-ALT-A

but it is inserting javascript style comments into my HTML file

```
// <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react.js"></script>
// <script src="./node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Which does nothing. Mystery solved. Thanks so much guys, you are great @num8er, etc.

I am going to submit this as a bug to the vscode folks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that it matters where you include the libraries. You can use `require("react")`, `<script src="./path/to/react.js"></script>` or import it.

Answer (score 0):

React.js is a framework that uses a language invented by Facebook called jsx. What react.js is is actually a compiler that compiles jsx down to pure javascript that has no dependencies on any external libraries.

There are two ways to compile jsx.

1. Compile jsx server-side which would generate a stand-alone js file that you can just include in your html.
2. For development purposes you can optionally include the `react.js` library in your html which would allow you to include jsx files directly to be compiled in the browser. Since this slows down page load it is not recommended to do this on production.

Since in your comment you mention you include the compiled js file instead of the jsx file in your html then you don't need to include anything else for React.js to work